# how to uniquely identify a client from server-side?

Tags: server-side, uniqueidentifier

**Objective:**

I want to detect if a web application is accessed from more than one account using the same device such as computer,mobile,tablet using different browser using any programming language or protocol

**So far:**

In Desktop application we read mac address to uniquely identify it.

In iOS mobile application we read UDID to uniquely identify it.

In Android application we read mac address as well to uniquely identify it.

In website reading client ip-address only seems to be viable way but it doesn't seem to be reliable due to NAT(Network address translator).

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: if it's about how to, I think googling is more suitable than asking here in SO.

Comment: Depends on the protocol also. HTTP has cookies exactly for this purpose.

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 I tried googling so far it seems impossible

Comment: @tripleee if the same user logins using different browser this approach fails

Comment: That's obviously a flaw of that particular approach, yes. If we are talking portable HTTP without client-side requirements, I'm afraid that's the best you can expect. For different protocols, there may be client-side requirements in the spec, but if we are talking generally for any network protocol, you get even less.

Comment: What malpractices? What suspects? I don't understand your question. Are you trying to use this for licensing perhaps?

Comment: Anyway, you can require cookies and require log-in. Then you know who's who.

Comment: @tripleee I mean I want to know how many users accessed my site using same computer.I can not use ip-address as a means to get this report as there are so many NATs,Proxies,VPNs between  a computer to public internet.So mac address is the only way to uniquely identify a computer but that's not possible to read as far as website is concerned so my question here is are there any other information that we can get from a http request other than ip-address to better classify the users.

Comment: No, there isn't, unless you force users to use cookies and/or log in.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for being patient with me replying to my comments and I really appreciated that !But cookie is bound to browser right ! we can't track if two accounts are used from two different browser on one system . correct me If I am wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading ip-address is the only way But with that also you can't trace exactly due to Network address translators,Proxy servers and VPN servers etc.

You have to understand this its privacy issue

Even in iOS also they have forbidden to read UDID right from iOS 7 as it infringes users privacy

Hope this solves your problem